# VSCode highlight PWD in Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Contrary to [changing the terminal to the present working directory](http://change%20the%20terminal%20to%20the%20current%20directory%20in%20visual%20studio%20code%20?) in VSCode, I'm looking for a way to get the present working directory in the focused integrated terminal and then highlight it in the Explorer. One way to do this would be using `code .`, but that opens up a new workbench if you're in a child directory. Is there a native way or an extension that supports doing this? Both command palette and keyboard shortcuts would work.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I can't find any APIs for:

1. Reading the CWD from the active terminal.
2. Changing the selected file in Explorer.

A workaround is to use `code ./some-file` to open it in the active Explorer.